# Descarga contenido html y guardar en BD

Tags: php

Necesito un script que se conecte a un sitio de subastas, las descargue y las guarde en una base de datos.

Este es un ejemplo de la información que aparece

Subasta: xxxxxxxxx

Valor Ofrecido: xxxxxxxxxxx

Bien: xxxxxxxxxxxx

Me podrían ayudar con una guía para hacerlo en PHP

Gracias

Comment: Has intentado algo? Pon una pregunta de una duda en concreto, adjuntando el código relacionado con el problema.

Comment: Hola Fabiola, bienvenida a [es.so]. Te comento que este sitio no se especializa en Mercado Pago, por lo que debes cumplir con las políticas de calidad que cumplimos todos. Te dejo esta dos guías: __"[ask]"__ y __"[mcve]"__.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para descargar el contenido html:

```
/* Para no limitar el tiempo de ejecución, se puede demorar */
set_time_limit(0);

$url = "http://urldelsitio"; 
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$html = fix($html);
$fileName = fileSave("bienes", $html);
$file = fopen($fileName, "r");
```

Luego iteras el archivo ubicando los bloques:

```
$strContent = "";
$strFile = "";
while (($line_detail = fgets($file)) !== false) {
    if (strpos($line_detail, "Subasta:") !== FALSE) {
         $strContent .= str_replace("Subasta:", "", line_detail) . ";";
    }

    /*.... Lo haces para cada linea ..... */

   if (strpos($line_detail, "Bien:") !== FALSE) {
       $strContent .= str_replace("Subasta:", "", line_detail) . ";";
       $strFile .= $strContent . "\n";
       $strContent = "";
   }

    /* al final obtienes la linea separada por comas  y así armas el csv */
}

/* Guardas el archivo */
$handlerFileCSV = fopen("file.csv", "a");
fwrite($handlerFileCSV, $strFile);
fclose($handlerFileCSV);

    /* Finalmente Importas el archivo a la BD, en la consola de linux o con un batch */

    mysql -vvvvv -u admin -pJl@2016.. -h localhost -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/$4' INTO TABLE <tabla> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' (<field1, field2, field3, ...>);" <base de datos>
```

Esta es una idea de cómo lo puedes hacer, entenderás que se requiere tiempo para terminarlo.

Saludos,

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio mucho tu ayuda

Comment: @FabiolaCendales Antes de dejar un comentario, en la caja de texto dice: _Utiliza los comentarios para pedir información o para sugerir mejoras. Evita los comentarios como "+1" o "gracias"._. Es probable que por el color gris no lo hayas visto. Te sugiero que borres el comentario.